# Бан по IP, помогите найти и устранить ошибку

Tags: php

Файл php:

```
$ipp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$banlist = file("/ip.txt");
$banlist = implode("\r\n", $banlist);
$ban = array($banlist);
$count = count($ban);
for ($il=0; $il<$count; $il++) {
if($ipp == $ban[$il]) { die("Вы забанены"); }
}
```

Файл ip.txt:

```
'85.26.184.19',
'85.28.184.19'
```

Данный скрипт работает если не использовать файла ip.txt, например:

```
...код...
$ban = array('85.26.184.19','85.28.184.19');
...код...
```

но нужно брать ipшники именно из файла, помогите исправить ошибку.

Comment: Функция file - уже создаёт массив. $ban = array($banlist); - это лишнее мне кажется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$banlist = file_get_contents('ipban.txt');
$search = strpos($banlist, $ip);
if ($search !== false)
die ("Вы забанены");
?>
```

Проверил у себя - работает :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
<?
  $ipp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $banlist = explode( "\n", file_get_contents( './ip.txt' ) );

  echo 'IP: '.$ipp.'<br>';

  if ( array_search( $ipp, $banlist ) ) die( 'Вы забанены' );
?>
```

Файл `ip.txt` ( для моего кода ) должен быть в папке со скриптом иметь вид:

```
127.0.0.1
ip2
ip3
```

Comment: timka_s, красиво написал)
shol, экпериментируйте с концом строки "\n"

Comment: например, что можно сделать с концом строки?

Comment: попробуйте так $banlist = explode( "**\\n**", file_get_contents( './ip.txt' ) );

Comment: не работает, все варианты перебрал с концом строки

Comment: хм, может я не так айпишники написал, как правильно их вписать в файл, нужно ли их разделять чем нить или просто столбиком написать?

Comment: Протестировал - всё работает... Обновил ответ - посмотрите с какого ip вы заходите, м.б. в этом дело

Comment: не работает, но я уже по другому сделал))))

Comment: Прокомментируйте, что как именно не работает - какой выводит ip и содержимое ip.txt